# Infinite Calendar Scrolling in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, date, datetime

I'm trying to implement an infinite calendar date scrolling option in react-native similar to the one showed here:
https://media.giphy.com/media/pbDTYVnnhMWkJK7rTk/giphy.gif

What's the best way to go about this?

What I'm trying to implement here is a 'to-do/task' tab that allows the user to view each date's tasks. I currently have it to where a new Date object is generated up to 30 days, but I feel this is not the best solution and ideally this instead can go to infinity (or ~5 years into the future).

Thanks!

Comment: That kinda looks like the Agenda component from [wix's calendar](https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars#agenda)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an example, you can use ***React-Native*** [FlatList](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#horizontal) with `horizontal=true` and `onEndReached` callback using which you will be able to add more dates when you reach the right end of your list.